# Why is identifier "MutexType" is undefined?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-mutex

Attempting to use the `boost` library to create a system wide mutex from the [docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html)

```
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/interprocess_mutex.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/scoped_lock.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/named_mutex.hpp>

using namespace boost::interprocess;

MutexType  mtx;


int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

I am running visual studio code and compiling my code using msys2-MINGW64 environment like so `g++ mutexes.cpp -lboost_system` but this does not seem to work and I am getting this error in the bash console

```
mutexes.cpp:8:1: error: 'MutexType' does not name a type
    8 | MutexType  mtx;
      | ^~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: A quick check of the boost documentation and I can see no type called `MutexType` what makes you think it exists?

Comment: If you are going by this [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html#interprocess.synchronization_mechanisms.mutexes) then you will see that `MutexType` is a type **you** are supposed to define, not one that boost defines for you.

Comment: @john i am following the docs check the link that i provided

Comment: Yes, please see my previous comment.

Comment: @john could you explain how to define a `MutexType`

Comment: scoped_lock is just  a wrapper around a mutex. So pick one of the other mutex types (eg. `interprocess_mutex` or `named_mutex`).

Comment: @john like so? `std::mutex mtx;`
    `scoped_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);`

Comment: Yes, I think so, not 100% sure if boost mutex is compatible with the mutexes in the standard library. Maybe you would know that better than me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked documentation specifically means "any mutex type":

```
//Let's create any mutex type:
MutexType mutex;
```

It follows it up with a concrete, more elaborate [Anonymous mutex example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html#interprocess.synchronization_mechanisms.mutexes.mutexes_anonymous_example) and [Named mutex example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html#interprocess.synchronization_mechanisms.mutexes.mutexes_named_example).

Which types are eligible is documented at `scoped_lock`:

> scoped_lock is meant to carry out the tasks for locking, unlocking, try-locking and timed-locking (recursive or not) for the Mutex. The Mutex need not supply all of this functionality. If the client of scoped_lock does not use functionality which the Mutex does not supply, no harm is done

In practice the minimal useful interface required will be that of the [standard library `BasicLockable` concept](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BasicLockable) although many mutex implementations also model [`Lockable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Lockable) and [`Mutex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Mutex) concepts.